# Lead acid battery cutoff voltage circuit

Tags: batteries

I've developed a device that runs on a 12V lead acid battery. The device will be deployed at a location where we cannot have physical contact with it. It is therefor not possible for us to detect the battery's voltage.

I want the battery to last as long as possible, but I don't want it to deep discharge. For this reason I wanted to implement a low current voltage cutoff circuit, but I am having trouble finding any. There are several that 50-100 mA, which already is too much.

What are low current cutoff devices or how can I make one?

Answer (score 1):

There are voltage monitor ICs, which perform this (or similar) functions, intended to disable (by logic signal) a circuit when voltage is low.  This one [LT2965](http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/2965fb.pdf)
seems suitable for your needs.  It works by detecting low voltage, and requires that your device take a logic signal input and cease consuming power.   There is a small current drain (at 12V, something under 10 uA), but most batteries can handle that for a year or two.

A 'turn-off' threshold should be set according to the lowest charge state at
the (coldest, if I understand lead-acid batteries) temperature.  The
'turn-on' threshold should be slightly higher, so that diurnal temperature
variations don't cause it to toggle.

Comment: That looks really interesting, seems to fit all my needs. Thank you.